# sql loader requires dat file to load the data

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a folder with several file s but they are not .dat. For my surprise i Could  load one file but only when I renamed to .dat . What Am I doing wrong or I need to rename all my files to .dat ?   My Files does not have  extensions

Thanks guys

controlfile

```
load data 
infile 'D:\pageviews\year=2016\month=06\*' 
replace
into table test
fields terminated by whitespace
trailing nullcols
(
c1,
c2,
c3,
c4
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `INFILE` clause you use is wrong.

You should name a file you're loading. Asterisk is used when data (you're about to load) is contained within the control file itself (after the `BEGINDATA` keyword).

If you don't specify a file extension, then it **defaults to .dat** (that's why you managed to load the file).

Possible cases (copied from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1008018)):

- Data contained in the control file itself: `INFILE  *`
- Data contained in a file named foo with a default extension of .dat: `INFILE  foo`
- Data contained in a file named datafile.dat with a full path specified: `INFILE 'c:/topdir/subdir/datafile.dat'`

Do read documentation; it'll be much more clear what you should (not) do.

Comment: I  am confused  on   if I want to load several files  like to use *.*

Comment: Come on, be serious. I posted a link and told you to read what's written in there. There's no point in me copy/pasting the *whole* document over here. If you took that effort, you'd see the "Specifying Multiple Datafiles" chapter which describes what you should do and how.

Comment: SOrry I didit  see the link

Comment: Probably because I used invisible ink :) OK, now that you spotted it, I really suggest you to read it. SQL*Loader is a nice tool, has plenty of options and will certainly help you do the job. Best of luck!